# Why does beamer change the item spacing when there are sub-items?

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

When an `\item` has another `itemize` environment inside it, the interline space to the preceding `\item` is slightly less than if threre is no sub-`itemize` (right image). This has the effect of bullet points "jumping around" between frames, if both frames happen to consist of items. Note that everything is okay with `\documentclass{article}` (left image).

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

[image: Okay] `<---------->` [image: Not okay]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Test material for illustration:
\def\line{\tikz[overlay] \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (0,1.3em);}
\def\stuff{Test \line}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
        \begin{itemize} % This causes weird spacing
            \item \stuff
        \end{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's missing a paragraph break. The space is consistent if you manually end the paragraph before the second level itemize with an explicit `\par` or a blank line.

Comment: Ah, I see. But why doesn't the `itemize` start a paragraph by itself? After all you can't use it in line with text, like a `tabular` for example. Any why is it correct in the `article` class?

Comment: Beamer has its own implementation of the itemize environment (you can find it in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) which is different from the standard LaTeX `itemize` we use in articles. I don't know if there are specific reasons for the current behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by dcmst, the problem can be solved by adding `\par` before each `itemize` environment. Instead of doing this manually, one can use the patching commands provided by the `etoolbox` package to patch the environment itself:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par}
```

Although the space between the `\item` and its sub-`itemize` is now a little larger, in my opinion this looks far better than the default. Also, the space between the "After:" and the first item is a bit larger. For this purpose, an additional negative space can be added after the `\par`:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par\vspace{-0.3em}}
```

[image: Here I fixed it]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Test material for illustration:
\def\line{\tikz[overlay] \draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++(0,1.3em) -- ++(-2em,0);}
\def\stuff{Test \line}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
Before:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
        \begin{itemize} % This causes weird spacing
            \item \stuff
        \end{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par}
After:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \stuff
        \end{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\par\vspace{-0.2em}}
Less space:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \stuff
        \end{itemize}
    \item \stuff
    \item \stuff
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]